# Stone age fiction with "summers" instead of "years"

Tags: identification-request

The series is fiction, and has multiple books. The cover I had of the third book has fire and an animal along with the protagonist, I think.
The protagonist is a person so it cancels out any books with animal protags. (*Mammoth Trilogy*, etc..)

The first book's cover is impossible to remember, but there was probably a scene involving winter, ice and maybe a river? Someone saves the protag.

The protagonist leaves his home, along with leaving the tribe that cared for him. Along the way, he seems to fall into an icy river? Another human saves him? The characters use "summers" instead of years, and the MCs are most likely teenagers.

I last read this book somewhere around 2017-2019, and can't remember any names at all. Winter is a conflict in the first book (freezing to death is bad apparently), so it's set around the ice age.

It was probably made after 2000, perhaps after 2010. If I were to give it an age rating, it would probably be PG? On-par with *Wings of Fire* and *Warriors*.

Comment: Do you remember any of the plot at all?

Comment: @Mithical My apologies, here's what I can muster up: The protagonist leaves his home, along with leaving the tribe that cared for him. Along the way, he seems to fall into an icy river? Another human saves him? The characters use "summers" instead of years, and the mcs are most likely teenagers. I'm sorry for the lack of help.

Comment: I've not read the series, but could it be _Earth's Children_? _The Clan of the Cave Bear_, _The Valley of Horses_, _The Mammoth Hunters_, _The Plains of Passage_, _The Shelters of Stone_, _The Land of Painted Caves_. I know too little about any of those books to make it an actual answer.

Comment: @SQB Those are all made by the same author, and I'm very sure this isn't it. Thank you for your help, nonetheless! The books also do have rather pretty / aesthetically pleasing covers, but that's just personal taste and shouldn't be used to help.

Comment: Okay, I was underway turning it into an answer anyway, just to be sure.

Comment: You might want to [edit] that into your question, about using "summers" instead of years.

Comment: The Chronicles of Ancient Darkness (Wolf Brother etc) fit quite well as well: they talk about people reaching their twelfth summer; the protagonist Torak is a teenager, with a friend called Renn; sometimes they live in a clan, sometimes they don't; there's definitely talk about surviving in snow, and I'm pretty sure someone falls in a river; published in mid-2000s — but I'd have thought you might have remembered the wolf!

Answer (score 4):

The tidbit about the characters using "summers" instead of years leads me to believe it is indeed the *[Earth's Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_Children)* series by [Jean M. Auel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_M._Auel) you're looking for.

The series chronicles the life of Ayla, a young Cro-Magnon girl, who gets adopted into a Neanderthal tribe, the titular *[Clan of the Cave Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clan_of_the_Cave_Bear)*. It is set in prehistorical Europe, around the time of the last Ice Age. She is cast out of the clan and treks around Europe, looking for "The Others": Cro-Magnon like herself. She travels with her lover Jolandar, looking for Jolandar's tribe.

A cover for the fourth book in the series, *[The Plains of Passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plains_of_Passage)*, looks a bit like what you've described (thanks to DavidW for the information):

[image: The cover of The Plains of Passage, showing two people with a dog near a fire, overlooking a plain with horses]

Although the UK covers may come closer to what you described in a comment as "rather pretty / aesthetically pleasing":

[image: The UK cover of Clan of the Cave Bears, showing a cave painting of a bear with a red background]

Comment: Just to note, the UK covers might fit more into the "pretty" aesthetic described by the OP? eg. [this](https://productimages.worldofbooks.com/0340268832.jpg)?  Have added to an edit of the post in case it helps.